# Pick value depending if row comes null or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure where I want to decide if pick one column or other depending if one is null. So I have two columns

`CreationDate` and `ModifiedDate`

And my select is something like this:

```
SELECT
            [P].[LegacyKey] AS [Job No]
           ,[P].[Name] AS [Proj Name]

            FROM Project AS [P]
```

I want to select `CreationDate` only if `ModifiedDate` equals to `NULL`, and if `ModifiedDate` is not null select it. How can I achieve that? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems want `coalesce()` :

```
SELECT [P].[LegacyKey] AS [Job No], [P].[Name] AS [Proj Name],
        COALESCE([P].ModifiedDate, [P].CreationDate)
FROM Project AS [P];
```

Comment: COALESCE detects if first value is null just put second one? or I need to do something like `COALESCE([P].ModifiedDate, [P].CreationDate, [P].CreationDate)` ?

Comment: COALESCE returns the first item in your list of parameters that has a value.  You can have multiple parameters.  "SELECT COALESCE(null, null, null, null, 'Hello There', null, 'Bingo')" returns "Hello There"

Answer (score 1):

Isnull() will also work:

```
SELECT
[P].[LegacyKey] AS [Job No],
[P].[Name] AS [Proj Name],
ISNULL([P].ModifiedDate, [P].CreationDate)

FROM Project AS [P]
```